# Problem assigning by reference

Tags: coding-standards

This code was working now it gives:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference

Code:

```php
$starredgroup = $myPage->getGroup($starredgroup);
$starredgroup_id = $starredgroup['groupid'];
$starredgroup_products =& $myPage->getStarredProducts($starredgroup_id);
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to have anything to do with WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're attempting to store output of a method by reference to `$starredgroup_products`, [which is not possible](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

This should fix it (untested):

```php
$starredgroup          = $myPage->getGroup( $starredgroup );
$starredgroup_id       = $starredgroup['groupid']; 
$starredgroup_products = $myPage->getStarredProducts( $starredgroup_id );
```